# What is the Broadcast Account?

Tags: notification

Under the notification envelope, there is something called "Set up Broadcast Account...". I've looked all over and can't find anything about it. What is it and what is it for? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://www.linuceum.com/Desktop/SocialMedia.php:

> Broadcast accounts are things like **Twitter**, **Facebook** or **Google Buzz**, which allow
>   you to send updates and share things with a number of friends or
>   followers over the internet. They allow you to keep up with
>   whatever your friends are doing. Unlike email, broadcasting is more
>   like a mail shot out to a group of people at the same time. It's not
>   just text that can be shared, but files, images and video (if your
>   connection's bandwidth allows)!
>
> Linux has a number of tools to handle broadcast messages, but the
>   default for Ubuntu is **Gwibber**. **Gwibber** allows you to define all your
>   social media accounts in one place, then to broadcast out across all
>   of them at the same time. As an example, the next section will show
>   you how to configure **Gwibber** with a Google Buzz account (-but the
>   priciple is the same for the likes of **Flickr**, **Facebook**, **Twitter**, etc).